# Receiving the error object in mocha afterEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

In my mocha testframework, I have an it-block that might throw an error. How do I obtain this error in the afterEach-hook that is called afterwards? Is there any workaround if it is not directly passed?

```
...

afterEach(async function () {
    var testObject = {
        title: this.currentTest.title,
        state: this.currentTest.state,
        duration: this.currentTest.duration,
        timedOut: this.currentTest.timedOut,
        error: this.currentTest.err // I want the error object here     
    }   
});

it('my title', () => {
        try {
            doSomethingThatMightThrowError();
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    });

....
```